# Dependency Analysis Error, XCode 4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to run a project developed in iOS 4 in XCode 4.6. I am running it on an iPhone 4.

I get the **error:**

```
Check dependencies

No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 i386).
```

I've updated my build settings to the following:

[image]

but still get the same error.  Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out had two targets.  Just needed to change build settings for 2nd target.